# Plotting frequency by date and type

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am studying more about plotting data in Python, but it seems very hard for me to plot this data. I have a dataset

```
    Date    Web
43  01/07/2020  www.cgs.com
59  01/09/2020  www.sintegratedsytems.com
193 01/21/2020  www.bbc.com
312 01/23/2020  www.wired.it
317 01/23/2020  www.bbc.com
... ... ...
9623    03/25/2020  www.greenstyle.com
9875    03/28/2020  www.wired.it
9892    03/28/2020  www.vanityfair.com
9920    03/28/2020  www.bbc.co.uk
10147   03/31/2020  www.bbc.co.uk
```

I would like to generate two plots:

- one showing the frequency of Web by date (this counts the number of webs on the same date)
- another one showing the frequency by date by Web (I think it should be done using a stacked plot; this counts the number of same webs on the same date)

For the first key point, I tried as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))

df_chart = df.groupby(['Date', 'Web']).size().reset_index()

sns.barplot(data= df_chart,x='Date',ax=ax1)
```

but the chart is empty and I got this error:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
> ```

due to `sns.barplot(data=dfg,x='Date',ax=ax1)`

For the second key point, I did

```
df['Date'].plot.bar(x='Date',y='Web', ax=ax, stacked=True)
```

but also this code does not work.

Can you tell me where are my mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.groupby('Date')['Web'].value_counts().unstack().plotb.bar()
```

Or

```
pd.crosstab(df['Date'], df['Web']).plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thank you @ Quang Hoang. This should be ok for the first key-point, should it not? I have tried with `df= df.pivot(columns='Web',index='Date').fillna(0)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,legend=True)
plt.show()`, but the labels use same colours and not one for each website  (maybe because I am considering many groups of webs?). For example: if I have bbc.com and wired.it, I would like they can be of different colour; however, the code returns the same colour (I have a list of 200 websites)

Comment: Maplotlib’s default color map has about 10 colors, I think. So you would see a lot of repeated colors. Also, I think that 200 are too many to be color-coded.

Comment: Thank you, Quang Hoang. Would fillna(0) alter the results? If I plot data using fillna and stacked = True the plot does not show any empty space

Comment: I don’t think so.